# How to find and close particular browser window from number of opened windows using Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation

Suppose there are five Browser windows opened, how to find the third one and close it through web driver?
Please I'm request you to all of you don't consider this question as a opinion based. I have this situation while working with my current project. There are number of windows gets opened while performing purchase section activity.

I have to close selected number of windows. What should I do using WebDriver?

Comment: Do they have different titles?

Comment: yes, most of the windows have different Titles.

Comment: The select that window by title and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution which I had used on IE(never tried on other browser).
Suppose you have 5 IE windows opened, perform the iterator on all the windows and save the window iterators in a variable which will be an Array:

```
String parentWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
//Click the button or link which populates the window
driver.findElement(By.id(actionBtn)).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
Set<?> popupHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
//SOP *popupHandles* 
Iterator<?> iterator = popupHandles.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
    String popupHandle = iterator.next().toString();
    if(!popupHandle.contains(parentWinHandle)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //Perform the operation you want to do
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWinHandle);
    }
}
```

Now pass the array index value to perform the close operation.

Comment: Good one...will try in my project..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code:

```
List<String> handles = (List<String>) driver.getWindowHandles();
// Switch to the third window.
driver.switchTo().window(handles .get(2));
// Close this window
driver.close()
```

Comment: Why do you initialize `thirdWindow`? You never use it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Removed it.